# How to click on "Cancel search" button programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I have a `<input type="search">`. For the purpose of UI testing, I want to click on the "cancel search" button:

[image: White search field on the teal background, with text "user", visible text cursor at the beginning of the input, search cancel button in a shape of the white cross on the gray circle, and awesome pixelated classic red arrow pointing at the cancel button with the text "this"]

The code for this snippet is just this:

```
<input type="search" value="user">
```

Cancel button itself can be styled via `::-webkit-search-cancel-button` pseudo, but because it's pseudo, it's not part of the DOM and I don't know how to access it. Only Blink/Webkit-based browsers render this button for now, but because my markup is used in the CEF application, it's not an issue.

Unfortunately, just setting the value to empty string does not fire any events. As far as I know, clicking on that button triggers "input" and "search" events, but firing them myself seems to defeat the purpose of UI testing.

So, how I can do this with Selenium or just plain Javascript?

Comment: I see what you mean, do you just want it to not visible?

Comment: @RobM., sorry what? No, I want to click it, like user would. It's part of UI, why would I want to hide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't know how to do it properly (and would appreciate any answers that know how to access that button), but came up with a workaround that worked for me.

The idea is to use Selenium ActionChains to actually move mouse pointer to the assumed location of the cancel button, and click there. Because I can't know for sure, where that button is, I assume that clicking on the point that is half the height from the right border, and is centered vertically, would work.

So, in my code I used the code similar to this:

```
def cancel_search(el: WebElement):
    driver = el.parent

    width, height = driver.execute_script(r'''
        const $el = $(arguments[0]);
        return [
            $el.outerWidth(true),
            $el.outerHeight(true),
        ];''', el)

    top = height // 2
    left = width - height // 2 - 1

    ac = ActionChains(driver)
    ac.move_to_element_with_offset(el, left, top)
    ac.click()
    ac.perform()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using .elementFromPoint(x, y) to get the cancel button.

If the (X) registers at all in the DOM or (I think) the Shadow DOM, this should simulate a mouse click,   I believe I read yesterday it is in Shadow DOM in Webkit and Blink browsers.

var x = //guess
   var y = //guess

```
var searchInput = document.getElementById('mySearchInput');

var searchCancelButton = e.elementFromPoint(x, y);  //  'get' cancel button element

searchCancelButton.click();
```

This way the xy coords should he absolute to the input box rather than the whole document.  If it is accessable in any DOM-style fashion, this should work, if you can guess the coordinates based on 0,0 being the input box's top-left corner.

Previously tried:

Try setting the value to "" THEN use the `.click()` DOM Element method.  If it had an ID you could use something like this example, but how you 'get' the element or reference it is transparent.

```
var e = document.getElementById('mySearchInput');
e.value = '';
e.click();
```

Comment: I have just tried this, but it does not trigger any events - http://jsfiddle.net/wmebnc8b/

Comment: For the updated answer: Shadow DOM is called so for a reason. With `elementFromPoint` you cannot find anything but what is already in DOM, and that button isn't, hence my question. So, `searchCancelButton === searchInput` in this case, and it won't work. Also, simulating the mouse event does not work, it seemingly wants trusted event.

Comment: Bummer.  I really wish they'd make these things openly accessible.  It's nice you can style it with CSS.  But why they dont make it accessible through JS?

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ who knows